# Not able to reduce the gap between the rows on the CK Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, ckeditor

My issue is when we try to copy from the word document to CKEditor the space between the lines is more then the space in the word document. The actual word doc has no space before or after the paragraph, but the CKEditor is adding unwanted space between the lines.

EG:
Word Doc:

Test Line1
Test Line2
Test Line3
 
Test Line4

CKEditor:(copy past result)
Test Line1

Test Line2

Test Line3

Test Line4

I tried most of the solutions avalibale on CKEditor forum and Stack Overflow.

https://jsfiddle.net/reoh7j74/98/

---js fiddle code--

```
<textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>

CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
config.language = 'es';
config.uiColor = '#F7B42C';
config.height = 300;
config.toolbarCanCollapse = true;
config.autoParagraph = false;
config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
config.shiftEnterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
};

CKEDITOR.on('editor1', function (ev) {
    ev.editor.dataProcessor.writer.setRules('p',
     {
         indent: false,
         breakBeforeOpen: false,
         breakAfterOpen: false,
         breakBeforeClose: false,
         breakAfterClose: false
     });
});

CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
```

At this point I am not sure if its even possible to achive the desired result. Any pointers in right directions will be helpful.
Thanks

Note:Some one suggested me to try a soft copy/past i.e.Ctrl+Shift+v and it works but I cannot propose tht as a solution.

Comment: When pasting from Word to your JSFiddle I don't get the extra space (Chrome && FF).

Comment: config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
config.shiftEnterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
should work. Try Refreshing the ckeditor page using Ctrl+R to clear browser cache.

Comment: Also don't test it in jsfiddle. As you can not clear cache there

Comment: @hungerstar The space in between the line is more then the word doc. I tried it on 2 different systems I still see the issue. You can easily reproduce by copying 2 line from word. but make sure you hit enter after the first line in word then type the second line.

Comment: @Scorpio my version of Word must work differently as hitting enter in mine creates a new paragraph (i.e. the example you have for `CKEditor:(copy past result)`) instead of returning to a new line (the example you have `EG: Word Doc:`). For me to get the result you have for `EG: Word Doc:` I have to use **SHIFT+ENTER**, not ENTER alone.